# Why can't a property be bound to function itself

Tags: javascript

I know that in order to bind a property to a function you need to add that to its prototype. For example:

```js
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

Animal.prototype.number = 20;
Animal.prototype.bark = function() {console.log('Woof')};
let mike = new Animal('Mike');
console.log(mike.number)
mike.bark();
```

Perhaps this is a very naive question, but why are you not allowed to bind a property to the function itself? For example, doing the following:

```js
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

Animal.bark = function() {console.log('Woof')};
Animal.number = 20;
let mike = new Animal('Mike');
console.log(mike.number)
mike.bark();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in JavaScript use prototypal inheritance. Every object inherits from some other object, or from `null`. This chain continues - all objects eventually inherit from `null`.

If an object inherits from another, all of the properties available on the parent object will be available on the child object (unless the child object defines a property with the same name, effectively shadowing and hiding the name on the parent).

If instances of Animal inherited from Animal itself, like with

```
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

Animal.bark = function() {console.log('Woof')};
Animal.number = 20;
```

Then instances of Animal would be inheriting from `function Animal`, which is a function - and would be functions and would also inherit `.call`, `.apply`, and so on. This is almost never what a developer would want.

Having a separate controllable object that instances inherit from makes more sense, and it was decided to make that object referenceable through `<functionName>.prototype`.

The prototype chain is:

```
instance <- Animal.prototype <- Object.prototype
```

and

```
Animal <- Function.prototype <- Object.prototype
```

Having instances also inherit from `Function.prototype` and be functions just wouldn't make sense. One almost always wants ordinary objects as instances, not callable functions.

Another benefit of having `Animal.prototype` being separate from `Animal` is that you can have both properties on the prototype and properties on the function or class itself, which is a nice way to separate instance values and methods from utility values and functions - which are associated with the class, but don't have to do with any instance in particular.

```js
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

Animal.prototype.bark = function() {console.log(this.name + ' says Woof')};
Animal.checkIsAnimal = function(possibleAnimal) {
  console.log('Is this an animal? ' + (possibleAnimal instanceof Animal));
};
const mike = new Animal('Mike');
Animal.checkIsAnimal({});
Animal.checkIsAnimal(mike);
```

Comment: oh that's such a wonderful explanation thanks so much. So basically, if I'm understanding correctly. Doing `<MyFunction>.prototype.<MyMethod>` adds a regular/instance method, but doing `<MyFunction>.<MyMethod>` adds a class method. Is that accurate? And unlike some other languages, in JS if the instance method is not found it does not look at the class methods to see if it exists there -- such as MRO in python.

Comment: From what I've heard, "class method" and "instance method" often refer to the same sort of thing - functions on the prototype. The generally accepted name for values on the class/function itself is *static methods* (or static properties). (they use the `static` keyword in `class`es too) Yes, with property lookup, it first checks the object itself, then if not found, on the object's internal prototype, and then on the next, and so on, until the prototype chain is exhausted.